# compare chars of two strings and ignore white space between words

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have **2 strings that use the same letters but one of them contains empty spaces at the end and between words**

```
const message = 'Hello javascript world ';
const message1 = 'Hello     javascript world              ' ;
```

i want to ignore these empty spaces from 2 strings to only compare strings by the rest of chars in order to get a boolean result equal to true when i do so *message === message1*

imo this need a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `str.replace(/\s+/g, '')` to remove the spaces then simply compare the strings
That would look something like this:

```js
const message = 'Hello javascript world ';
const message1 = 'Hello     javascript world              ' ;

const equal = message.replace(/\s+/g, '') == message1.replace(/\s+/g, '');
// true
```

Comment: what + means in the regex ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function utilizing the [String.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method like so:

```js
const message = 'Hello javascript world ';
const message1 = 'Hello     javascript world              ' ;


const stringsMatch = (str1, str2) =>  str1.replaceAll(' ', '') == str2.replaceAll(' ', '')

console.log(stringsMatch(message, message1))
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with regex like you mentioned

```js
const stringsMatchRegex = (str1, str2) =>  str1.replace(/ /g, '') == str2.replace(/ /g, '')


console.log(stringsMatchRegex(message, message1))
```

---

I would suggest also using [String.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) on both strings to bypass character case:

```js
const stringsMatch = (str1, str2) =>  str1.replaceAll(' ', '').toLowerCase() == str2.replaceAll(' ', '').toLowerCase()
```